# how to implement Jmf

Tags: java, video, netbeans, streaming, jmf

how to implement jmf in netbeans?and how to build video streaming using JMF?

Comment: Why don't you google it first..try something and ask here when you are stuck with something?

Comment: I've tried to apply the JMF to netbeans, but can not walk

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the [JMF framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)
2. See the [Code Samples and Apps](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-141145.html)